# How to inject (Register service) a non generic class with generic methods in .Net c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following class and I want to register it in startup class via service.
How can I do that? Also if it is possible let me know how can I register it via Interface.

The following is an example of non generic class with generic methods.

```
public class HTTPClientHelper
{
     
        public HTTPClientHelper()
        {
            Init();
         
        }

        private HttpClient _httpClient;

        private void Init()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MimeTypes.ApplicationJSON));
        }
  
        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            T data;
            try
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string d = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (d != null)
                    {
                        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(d);
                        return (T)data;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            object o = new();
            return (T)o;
        }

        public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url, HttpContent contentPost)
        {
            T data;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, contentPost))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string d = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (d != null)
                {
                    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(d);
                    return (T)data;
                }
            }
            object o = new object();
            return (T)o;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You register it like you do any class, whether it has generic methods or not, it makes no difference.

Comment: It is the caller who specifies the type parameter of the method.